# How can I remove Google Chrome from Unity launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, google-chrome, icons, unity-dash

When I first installed Ubuntu, I installed google chrome directly by a terminal by running some commands that I found in another thread, I don't remember which ones, something like `apt-get` I think. I then opened it again by a terminal using the command `google-chrome-stable` and after some time I thought I should probably lock the icon that appeared in the launcher on the left. The problem is that when I closed it and pressed it again it wouldn't open, I had to find the normal chrome icon from Dash and then when I clicked that it opened the previous icon that I had locked the first time.

[Here's what happens when I click the normal chrome icon in case I confused you.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpGHG.jpg)

This has been happening ever since no matter if I have locked either chrome icon in the launcher or not. I tried these:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-stable
(reinstalled)
$ sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
$ rm ~/.config/google-chrome/ -rf
(reinstalled)
$ sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
(reinstalled)
```

but none of it worked, the problem persists. How can I make chrome open in the same icon and get rid of the other one that opens?

**Edit**: More context: The problem goes away right after I reinstall. If I restart my pc though the problem comes back up.

Comment: @Fabby OK did it! I have to wait 20 hours though to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it! Here is what I did:

Check this folder using this command:

```
ls ~/.local/share/applications
```

If there are some Google stuff in it remove it. If you want to remove it altogether use:

```
rm ~/.local/share/applications/google*
```

Comment: `rm -rf ~/.local/share/applications` will remove **all** your local .desktop files!!